# Timer causing IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, exception, timer, indexing, xna

I have some code resembling the code below. Its a bit more complicated, but essentially at seeming random times during my game I get an `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

When I read more details, it says the Exception occured on the parameter "index" (I don't have one name that, so I thought it might be from the `List<Rectangle>`).

```
void Update()
{
    CurrentIndex++
    if(CurrentIndex > EndFrame)
    {
        CurrentIndex = StartFrame;
    }
}

public override Rectangle GetSize(Vector2 position)
{
    //Exception occurs here
    return new Rectangle(
        (int)(position.X + MaxCharacterSize.X - AnimationList[CurrentFrame].BoundingBox.Width),
        (int)(position.Y + MaxCharacterSize.Y - AnimationList[CurrentFrame].BoundingBox.Height),
        AnimationList[CurrentFrame].BoundingBox.Width,
        AnimationList[CurrentFrame].BoundingBox.Height);
}
```

Why is this throwing an Exception? It's hard to even debug because it seems to happen so randomly. Could it be something with the fact the `Update()` is only ever called by a `Timer.Elapsed` event?

I will be forever grateful to someone who can answer it.

Comment: Okay I can try to do that if it gets thrown again. It only gets thrown every 20 minutes or so. I figured it had to be in my AnimationList. Cause that's the only thing that takes a parameter called index.

Comment: Could be multithread issue. If thread one has executed `CurrentIndex++` (and that made it greater than EndFrame) but not `CurrentIndex = StartFrame`, and thread two calls GetSize, it will try to access past the end of your arrays.

Comment: The parameter index fault is not a variable called index. Parameter Index means the index for that object itself. Arrays and Lists both have indexes. Example listItem[0] will get the instance at index 0 for the object.  What line is the error occuring on ? That will tell you what object is giving the index exception and what object to debug.

Comment: The object is AnimatedList. The index I pass in to the [ ]. What I think is happening is the index increments to the max. And just before the GetSize method finishes the timer shoots again and increments it passed

Comment: You can avoid going over indexes by checking to make sure the index is not above the count of objects in the list then run the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without a good code example. However, most likely your Timer.Elapsed event is being raised on a thread other than the one handling the GUI. So you have a race condition where it's possible for the timer to increment the index, but not yet wrap it around before that thread is temporarily suspended and your GUI thread tries to use the (now invalid) index.

One way to fix it:

```
void Update()
{
    int newIndex = CurrentIndex + 1;
    if(newIndex > EndFrame)
    {
        newIndex = StartFrame;
    }
    CurrentIndex = newIndex;
}
```

Now all that said, (again) without a better code example, it's not possible to see what other threading bugs you might have. The above assumes that CurrentIndex is "volatile" and that EndFrame and StartFrame won't change while these other threads are running.

Comment: I suggest `CurrentIndex = (CurrentIndex == EndFrame) ? StartFrame : CurrentIndex + 1;`.

Comment: That was what I was worried about, but I wasn't sure if it was plausible, as I have not yet really Learned about threading in classes yet. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

The exception is because `CurrentIndex` has a value that is beyond the end of the `AnimationList` list.

Without full code it's hard to say, but the two things I would look at are:

1. Make sure `EndFrame` is not off-by-one (i.e., make sure it wasn't initialized to the *length* of AnimationList, because if it was then AnimationList[EndFrame] is invalid and will throw that exception)
2. Make sure the `Update()` routine can't fire in a different thread from your `GetSize()` method. If it is (and has to be), then you need some synchronization to prevent `GetSize()` from being called between the time the `CurrentIndex` is incremented and the check for reaching the end of the list is reached.

Comment: I don't really have multithreading at all. Timers are the only things that may be executing in a thread. So there are those.